# Why am I getting an error based on my parameterized constructor being called when I try to instantiate an object using my default constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, default-constructor

**Any thoughts as to why I am unable to call the default constructor?**

Here is a small part of the class so that you can see the available constructors and some of the data members:

```
class TweetExplorer:

    CLEAN_OUTPUT_PATH = constants.CLEAN_OUTPUT_PATH

    # Authorization keys
    API_KEY = ''
    API_SECRET_KEY = ''
    ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

    OUTPUT_PATH = '' 

    API_ACCESS = 0

    def __init__(self):

        self.OUTPUT_PATH = constants.OUTPUT_PATH 
        self.CLEAN_OUTPUT_PATH = constants.OUTPUT_PATH


def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret_key, access_token, access_token_secret):

    self.API_KEY = api_key
    self.API_SECRET_KEY = api_secret_key
    self.ACCESS_TOKEN = access_token
    self.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = access_token_secret

    try: 
        self.check_access()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    self.OUTPUT_PATH = constants.OUTPUT_PATH
```

So, in the same file, I attempt to instantiate an instance of the class by using the default constructor:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    explorer = TweetExplorer()
```

Instead of calling the default constructor, I get the following error:

> Message=**init**() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'api_key', 'api_secret_key', 'access_token', and 'access_token_secret'
>     Source=C:\source\repos\TweetExplorer\TweetExplorer.py
>     StackTrace:
>     File "C:\source\repos\TweetExplorer\TweetExplorer.py", line 499, in 
>       explorer = TweetExplorer()

Comment: You cannot override the `__init__` method in this way. The second definition "overwrites" the first

Comment: I figured that there was some sort of rule with the default constructors, but I wasn't able to find anything. So how would you recommend instantiating an object without passing any arguments to a constructor?

Comment: For your case: is the first constructor even valid? I don't imagine that a tweet explorer would be any good without any credentials

Comment: Otherwise, you can just have the parameters as keyword arguments that default to None

Comment: To answer your first question - yes. I quickly found out that I was only able to obtain the most recent 3,240 tweets using the API, so the alternative was to web-scrape the tweets. That being said, there is still value in using the API. It is faster and provides slightly more information than I cared to scrape myself.

Comment: @IainShelvington in regard to defaulting the parameters to None, that will certainly work, but I don't like allowing the class to be instantiated with some but not others.. I can certainly set a boolean condition to only set the parameters if all values were passed, but it just seems messy.

Comment: Added an answer that uses classmethods to provide multiple constructors

Comment: Python != Java. There is no default constructor, and you cannot overload methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern I have used before for providing multiple constructors is to use `classmethod`s:

```
class TweetExplorer:

    CLEAN_OUTPUT_PATH = constants.CLEAN_OUTPUT_PATH
    API_ACCESS = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.OUTPUT_PATH = constants.OUTPUT_PATH
        self.CLEAN_OUTPUT_PATH = constants.OUTPUT_PATH
        self.API_KEY = ''
        self.API_SECRET_KEY = ''
        self.ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
        self.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

    @classmethod
    def with_credentials(cls, api_key, api_secret_key, access_token, access_token_secret):
        obj = cls()

        obj.API_KEY = api_key
        obj.API_SECRET_KEY = api_secret_key
        obj.ACCESS_TOKEN = access_token
        obj.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = access_token_secret

        try:
            obj.check_access()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

        return obj
```

Now you can initialise `TweetExplorer` without any arguments

```
TweetExplorer()
```

Or with the creds

```
TweetExplorer.with_credentials(api_key, api_secret_key, access_token, access_token_secret)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Python will override the first declaration of **init**.
To achieve optional parameters with default values you can do something like

```
def __init__(self, api_key='', api_secret_key='', access_token='', access_token_secret=''):
    self.API_KEY = api_key
    self.API_SECRET_KEY = api_secret_key
    self.ACCESS_TOKEN = access_token
    self.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = access_token_secret
```